# Django dev environment to mimic production?

Tags: python, django, virtual-machine, virtualenv

I'm writing a Django app that will eventually be deployed to an IaaS, most likely Amazon. I'd like to develop in an environment that's both a) sandboxed from my local machine and b) as similar like the target system as possible -- kind of like what Foreman does for Heroku apps. I'm using virtualenv which is great, but I'd also like something to start/stop my Postgres server, handle environment variables, manage helper processes like celery if I need them down the line. I've looked into Docker but I get the impression it's not quite there yet. Are there any other more tried and true options out there? I've come across Vagrant, Chef, and Supervisor but I can't get a good sense of what does what. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it's more suitable for here or for [`serverfault.com`](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Vagrant is your friend with that, I run all of my sandboxed sites in a vagrant server combined with git which allows me to easily transfer sites between servers.

Comment: That sounds like the way to go, I'll check it out!